# How to access images from a HTML page

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, httpd.conf

how to access images from a html web page.
I am a newbie for linux and trying to learn

I have  images in this location /shutterfly/web/htdocs/images

how to  embed the image link in the html source code .  anything I need to update in the httpd.conf file or .htaccess file

www.example.com/images/facebook.jpg

scenerio below in the source code

thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain you problem more nicely please.

I mean what's different in linux for adding images in html code.
We always use `<a href = "">` for adding links or locations of images.

please explain your problem once more.